# can't resolve "valid identity is not found"?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to develop my first iOS App on my mac (OS 10.8), the application contains a push notification service. I followed the below steps to create my App ID:

- Give a name to the APP ID
- Set the Bundle ID.
- Check the Push Notification checkbox
- Create App ID
- Generate a certificate, by uploading the request created by key chain access, then downloading and installing it on key chain access, exporting into .p12 file.
- Create Provision Profile, Download and install on my Xcode organiser (XCode 4 updated version) and on my device to test.

The project work well on the simulator (except get the token and that's normal). However when installing the provisioning profile on the Xcode Organizer it gave me :"valid identity is not found".

Checked and tested Many Solutions:

- Delete Cert from Dev Center and Key Chain Access.
- Delete Provision profile recreate it.
- Install provision profile directly from Xcode.
- Delete Created Keys from key chain and create new ones.

Many suggestion has been provided:

- Your Keychain is missing the private key associated with your iPhone Developer or iPhone Distribution certificate.
- Your Keychain is missing the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Intermediate Certificate.
- Your certificate was revoked or has expired.
- Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP) or Certificate Revocation List (CRL) are turned on in Keychain Access preferences

None of the above fixed the problem.

Would you please provide a solution for this problem and thank you in advanced.

Comment: First, make sure that you have Apple's development root certificates installed. Without them, provisioning profiles may not be valid. Additionally, ensure that you have your iOS Development keys, both the certificate and private key, in your keychain.

Answer (score 1):

i had discover my problem. i work in a company and there is my partner have generate the developpements certificate on his own mac. i work on a different mac. so what i need, he must export the key and the certificate from his key chain access and give it to me.
that's it.
beginner's problem :d

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure your Bundle Identifier match with the bundle Identifier included in the   provisioning profile. And you have correctly added your iPhone's UDID to the developer account under devices and then add the bundle identifier and device to the provisional profile. Also make sure you have requested the certificate from your own Mac and then installed the certificate after downloading it from the developer account. And there will be a key under your certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Many things may go wrong, so simply try these steps, even if you've done them before.

- Make sure your Bundle identifier is the same at both in Xcode and in iTunes Connect, it's a good practice to fill it manually instead of Xcode's template, as it *IS* case-sensitive.
- Check that your testing device's UDID is listed on the Devices list at `developer.apple.com`.
- Create a new provisioning profile with a new unique name, for your app's bundle ID, make sure, again, that it's the same bundle ID (case sensitive) and make sure you have your newly-added device UDID (or the existing one if you had it correct before) in on the provisioning profile. Take a note of the developer certificate that the provisioning profile is bound to.
- Download the newly created provisioning profile AND the development certificate that the provisioning profile is for. Clean your project's build folder (open Product menu from the menu bar, press and hold down the option button on your keyboard, and select 'Clean Build Folder...', exit Xcode.
- Open both your provisioning profile and certificate. One should open in Xcode, the latter, in Keychain access.
- In Keychain access, make sure you have the private key to your non-expired, non-revoked developer certificate. (if not, you need to either find its private key (e.g. in another keychain or in another Mac. It should be on the Mac that the CSR is created on, or if none are available, revoke it and create a new certificate, and start over this process)
- In Xcode, make sure you are using the provisioning profile, *NOT* overriding it (e.g. you've selected a different value under 'Debug' or 'Release' options by mistake).
- In Xcode, make sure you are using the correct development certificate (the one that is bound to the provisioning profile) and not overriding it under Code-signing identity section's Debug or Release, or in 'Any iOS SDK' sub-item underneath them. If everything worked, Xcode should offer you the correct certificate for your provisioning profile.
- Your project should build. Seriously, I can't think of anything else.